# MWS - how to get price of all offers

Tags: amazon-mws

I am trying to get all my products with their prices.

With reports API(inventory report) I am able to get the table containing my products with their SKU's and ASIN's.

But when I try to use this SKU's/ASIN's with products API (GetCompetitivePricingForSKU/ASIN, GetLowestOfferListingsForSKU/ASIN, GetLowestPricedOffersForSKU/ASIN, GetMyPriceForSKU/ASIN), I get the error "does not have access to the given marketplace".

Can someone tell me if this is the right way to use the API?

Comment: You can only access product's information for the marketplace you are selling i.e. if you have amazon seller account in uk and with your amazon uk account's API credentials you can't access any product's information even if it sold by you on amazon france.

Comment: Well..I have amazon seller account in UK, table from inventory report is from UK, but when I try to use previously mentioned functions(...somethingForSKU/ASIN) for obtained ASIN's and SKU's on UK marketplace, I still get the error. This should be working, right?

Comment: I can help further if I can see your code.

Comment: I don't test the API using my own code. I use amazon mws scratchpad(https://mws.amazonservices.co.uk/scratchpad/index.html), and I am still getting the error. So problem shouldn't be in the code.

Comment: You can use `Sellers` API section and method `ListMarketplaceParticipations` to get marketplaces you are able to use.

Answer (score 0):

I just did GetCompetitivePricingForASIN and i got this result
[image]

Comment: Yes, I can get this result too..but only when I get random ASIN's from GetMatchingProductForId.

Comment: But I need to solve the situation where I don't know what products I have and find detailed info about them.

Comment: Mate you need either ASIN or SKU to use any of these methods, I don't know what you are trying to achieve. You really need to change your question and explain people what you are trying to do and some code to start  with.

Comment: I know I need ASIN or SKU for those operations... I am able to get my ASIN's and SKU's from inventory report. But when I use them with the products API, then it doesn't work.